# How to delay transaction open in EF6?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, transactions, entity-framework-6, autofac, entity-framework-plus

We use ASP.Net MVC + Autofac + EF6.
DbContext is wrapped by UnitOfWork. We create it for each http request via Autofac.
We also open transaction for whole http request in UnitOfWork constructor.

The problem is that not all http requests have to be wrapped in to the transaction. Some of them even don't have requests to DB.

We'd like to delay transaction open till the first actual request to DB.
Any ideas how one can do it?

We can override SaveChages and open transaction before save, but select queries will not be executed in transaction this way.

One more problem here: we use global filters from EF Plus for soft removable entities. It works good, but filters initialization for context is rather slow. We'd like to delay it till the first actual request to DB too.

Comment: Why do you need to create a transaction while EF6 does it for when it's needed?

Comment: EF wraps each SaveChages in separate transaction (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/saving/transactions#what-ef-does-by-default). We need to rollback several SaveChanges if http request fails.

Comment: Okay, I see, thanks. So I believe that the problem with injection `UnitOfWork` during controller construction despite an action gets called, right? If so, then consider using [lazy injection](https://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/resolve/relationships.html#delayed-instantiation-lazy-b) or similar approach.

Comment: Thank you, lazy DbContext initialization helped!

Comment: I've turned my comment into the answer. I'll be really grateful if you accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `UnitOfWork` is injected into controller despite an action being called and therefore its constructor is always called even if you don't need to use it. One solution could be using Autofac [lazy injection](https://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/resolve/relationships.html#delayed-instantiation-lazy-b). In this case `UnitOfWork`'s constuctor is called only when its instance is needed

```cs
public class SomeController : Controller {
    //..
    private readonly Lazy<IUnitOfWork> _unitOfWork;

    private IAnotherService UnitOfWork => _unitOfWork.Value;

    public SomeController(
        //..
        Lazy<IUnitOfWork> unitOfWork
        )
    {
        //..
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    }

    //..
    public ActionResult ActionNeedsTransaction()
    {
        //use UnitOfWork

        UnitOfWork.SaveChanges();

        return Json(value);
    }

}
```